# Download large dataset using interactive grid oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1, interactive-grid

I've created an interactive grid report using a complex sql query.

This is a very fine-tuned SQL query. And loads Millions of data in 2-3 seconds on apex as well. But usually filtered record count will be between 150k - 300k.

When it comes to download the data, when clicked on download button, there was a delay of 2-3 mins till the download gets started.

Between this period there is no update in console or network as well.

Initially I though at click on download it may have to process data again. And thus, I've created a temporary table in which I stored the data and then get it into IG. I thought it could speed up the process since it has to get data from single table only. But no use. It still taking time to start downloading process.

So, is there any way to quickly start this process?
Or at least any way to add a spinner when clicked on downlaod?

Comment: When you run the query in the report, it only fetches the rows that are displayed on the screen. Not much data needs to be send from server to client. A download is completely different. The entire dataset needs to be prepared on the server side and then send to the client. Since you say "millions of data", that is probably the reason. Not sure an interactive grid is a good method of downloading millions of rows though...

Comment: Actually while downloading we do set parameters hence record count usually gets reduced to 150k - 300k.

Comment: I'd suggest looking into apex apex_data_export.

Comment: I'm getting `ORA-06550: line 3, column 15: PLS-00201: identifier 'APEX_DATA_EXPORT.T_EXPORT' must be declared`. Is this feature available in `oracle-apex-19.1`?

Comment: well... you can check that easily yourself here: apex.oracle.com/doc191 - but no, apparently it was introduced in 20.2. 19.1 is over 3 years old, you might want to consider upgrading.